# Pine Script Strategy that records conditions from indicators on a frame of bars (a certain number of bars)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

I have created a custom indicator that fuses 4 different indicators, each indictor has a buy and sell boolean signal. My indicator requires 3 out of the 4 buy signals to be true in order to send a buy signal and vise versa for sell. My problem is that pine script runs the script on every bar therefore checking the 4 indicators conditions on a single bar and returning a buy signal if 3 out of the 4 conditions are true on a single bar. What I want to accomplish is to send a buy signal if 3 out of 4 are true on a frame of bars. For example on a frame of 10 bars (ind1 true on bar1, ind2 true on bar 4, ind3 false on bar6, ind4 true on bar10)if 3 of the 4 are true in this frame a buy signal should be sent(or plotted). Is this possible in any way?

I have read the pine script documentation but couldnt find anything of use

Answer (score 0):

Without providing the code, its hard to provide proper guidance that fits into your existing work.

I suggest looking into defining those four 'Indicators' (maybe "Case" or "Scenario" is a better phrase to use?") into [UDT](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Objects.html)'s and add an e.g.  "status" field as bool you update on every bar.

Then count the status fields that are "true" and if the result is >= 3,  execute your signal.

Comment: The problem is that i want the buy signal for each indicator on a window of bars, so i want the conditions on lets say a time frame of 5 bars for all the indicators

Comment: Sorry mate. No offense. I just  kinda feel we specify the terms you use differently. I simply can't make sense of your ask without code. Maybe some people smarter than me chime in/make sense of your ask. Good luck.